# On Linux Mint host, my Windows 10 VM isn't passing through audio

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware

My Windows 10.0 19044 is a physical installation I like to VM into, however even with VMWare Tools installed, it's not passing through audio. When I launch into the physical installation, there is audio, but on my Linux there is no application audio listed in my sound settings for the VM. Other VMs do have audio.

I'm using VMWare Workstation 16.2.3 build-19376536. Windows 10 lists the sole audio device as "Speakers (2- High Definition Audio Device)" with the most up to date drivers already installed.

Here's the vmx file.

```
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "19"
mks.enable3d = "TRUE"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
nvram = "Windows 10 and later x64.nvram"
virtualHW.productCompatibility = "hosted"
gui.exitOnCLIHLT = "FALSE"
powerType.powerOff = "soft"
powerType.powerOn = "soft"
powerType.suspend = "soft"
powerType.reset = "soft"
displayName = "Windows 10 and later x64"
usb.vbluetooth.startConnected = "TRUE"
firmware = "efi"
sensor.location = "pass-through"
guestOS = "windows9-64"
vpmc.enable = "TRUE"
tools.syncTime = "FALSE"
numvcpus = "6"
cpuid.coresPerSocket = "3"
memsize = "16384"
mem.hotadd = "TRUE"
sata0.present = "TRUE"
nvme0.present = "TRUE"
nvme0:0.fileName = "Windows 10 and later x64-0.vmdk"
sata0:1.deviceType = "cdrom-raw"
sata0:1.fileName = "/dev/cdrom"
sata0:1.present = "TRUE"
usb.present = "TRUE"
ehci.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci.present = "TRUE"
svga.graphicsMemoryKB = "8388608"
ethernet0.addressType = "generated"
ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000e"
serial0.fileType = "thinprint"
serial0.fileName = "thinprint"
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
serial0.present = "TRUE"
extendedConfigFile = "Windows 10 and later x64.vmxf"
nvme0:1.deviceType = "rawDisk"
nvme0:1.fileName = "Windows 10 and later x64-0.vmdk"
nvme0:0.deviceType = "rawDisk"
numa.autosize.cookie = "60032"
numa.autosize.vcpu.maxPerVirtualNode = "6"
uuid.bios = "56 4d 4e 2e a1 cc 34 9e-4d 49 39 30 2a a3 60 e3"
uuid.location = "56 4d cc 26 08 1d 79 0f-44 d2 47 41 50 9c 2b f5"
vm.genid = "8724792138857890031"
vm.genidX = "-8964534315457435113"
nvme0:0.redo = ""
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
pciBridge5.pciSlotNumber = "22"
pciBridge6.pciSlotNumber = "23"
pciBridge7.pciSlotNumber = "24"
usb.pciSlotNumber = "32"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "160"
ehci.pciSlotNumber = "34"
usb_xhci.pciSlotNumber = "192"
sata0.pciSlotNumber = "35"
nvme0.pciSlotNumber = "224"
svga.vramSize = "268435456"
vmotion.checkpointFBSize = "4194304"
vmotion.checkpointSVGAPrimarySize = "268435456"
vmotion.svga.mobMaxSize = "1073741824"
vmotion.svga.graphicsMemoryKB = "8388608"
vmotion.svga.supports3D = "1"
vmotion.svga.baseCapsLevel = "9"
vmotion.svga.maxPointSize = "189"
vmotion.svga.maxTextureSize = "32768"
vmotion.svga.maxVolumeExtent = "16384"
vmotion.svga.maxTextureAnisotropy = "16"
vmotion.svga.lineStipple = "1"
vmotion.svga.dxMaxConstantBuffers = "15"
vmotion.svga.dxProvokingVertex = "0"
vmotion.svga.sm41 = "1"
vmotion.svga.multisample2x = "1"
vmotion.svga.multisample4x = "1"
vmotion.svga.msFullQuality = "1"
vmotion.svga.logicOps = "1"
vmotion.svga.bc67 = "9"
vmotion.svga.sm5 = "1"
vmotion.svga.multisample8x = "1"
vmotion.svga.logicBlendOps = "1"
ethernet0.generatedAddress = "00:0C:29:A3:60:E3"
ethernet0.generatedAddressOffset = "0"
vmci0.id = "715350243"
monitor.phys_bits_used = "45"
cleanShutdown = "FALSE"
softPowerOff = "FALSE"
usb:1.speed = "2"
usb:1.present = "TRUE"
usb:1.deviceType = "hub"
usb:1.port = "1"
usb:1.parent = "-1"
checkpoint.vmState = ""
sata0:1.startConnected = "FALSE"
toolsInstallManager.lastInstallError = "0"
svga.guestBackedPrimaryAware = "TRUE"
tools.remindInstall = "FALSE"
toolsInstallManager.updateCounter = "2"
guestInfo.detailed.data = "architecture='X86' bitness='64' buildNumber='19044' distroName='Windows' distroVersion='10.0' familyName='Windows' kernelVersion='19044.1706' prettyName='Windows 10 Home, 64-bit (Build 19044.1706)'"
isolation.tools.hgfs.disable = "FALSE"
sharedFolder0.present = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.enabled = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.readAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder0.hostPath = "/home/ram/Torrents"
sharedFolder0.guestName = "Torrents"
sharedFolder0.expiration = "never"
sharedFolder1.present = "TRUE"
sharedFolder1.enabled = "TRUE"
sharedFolder1.readAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder1.writeAccess = "TRUE"
sharedFolder1.hostPath = "/home/ram/.steam/debian-installation"
sharedFolder1.guestName = "Steam"
sharedFolder1.expiration = "never"
sharedFolder.maxNum = "2"
hgfs.mapRootShare = "TRUE"
gui.lastPoweredViewMode = "fullscreen"
ethernet0.linkStatePropagation.enable = "TRUE"
floppy0.present = "FALSE"
sound.present = "TRUE"
sound.pciSlotNumber = "33"
sound.virtualDev = "hdaudio"
nvme0:0.present = "TRUE"
tools.upgrade.policy = "useGlobal"
usb_xhci:4.present = "TRUE"
usb_xhci:4.deviceType = "hid"
usb_xhci:4.port = "4"
usb_xhci:4.parent = "-1"
unity.wasCapable = "TRUE"
sound.autoDetect = "TRUE"
sound.fileName = "-1"
```

I've tried setting explicit sound devices in the VM too, to no avail.

Am I missing something? Any help's appreciated!